# How to start all the appservers using wsadmin jython script?

Tags: python, websphere, jython, websphere-8, wsadmin

I am trying to start all the appservers managed by a DMGR using Jython, I have come up with this script but it is not working. Can anyone guide me what could be wrong here.

```
server = AdminConfig.list( 'Server' );
mbean  = AdminConfig.getObjectName( server );
AdminControl.invoke( mbean, 'restart' );

# combined into a single statement, this would be:

AdminControl.invoke( AdminConfig.getObjectName( AdminConfig.list( 'Server' ) ), 'restart' );
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a library of jython functions that probably handles it here 
https://github.com/wsadminlib/wsadminlib.  Look for startAllServersInCluster

Comment: Hi Bruce, Thanks I got it. The very first method about getting CLUSTER Name is not working.

Comment: def getServerClusterByName( name ):
 241    """Return the config object id for the named server cluster
 242    TODO: get rid of either this or getClusterId"""
 243    return getObjectByName( 'ServerCluster', name )    is this the right method to get Cluster name ?